# Possible to manage identity range in SQL server?

Tags: sql, identity

Is it possible to manage an identity range in SQL Server?

If I set **seed** in DB one on 1 and in DB two on 10000

In this scenario if I **sync both** DB's, DB one just adds on 10000

Let's say I want this:

- DB1 -> id start [0 - 9000]
- DB2 -> id start [10000 - 19000]

**SOLUTION:**

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.* WITH NOCHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT Id_Range_Constraint
    CHECK(ID BETWEEN 10000 AND 19999)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create constraints in both databases for the ranges specified in your question. But keep in mind that `INSERT` will fail as soon as records fall outside that range.

Something along these lines, for SQL Server. Other RDBMS syntax will vary slightly:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
  Id Int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(0, 1)
);

ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT Id_Range_Constraint
CHECK (Id BETWEEN 0 AND 9000);

DROP TABLE T;
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need a check on the DB1 as @Yuck said and on DB2, create the identity as:

```
id int not null primary key identity (10000,1),
```